# How to Capitalize first letter of word

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my input txt file

```
i like apple and i love to eat apple.are you like to eat apple.
```

I want to output this file into another text file, where a new line must be inserted after full stop and each word must be capitalized, like we use Toupper in php or python. How would I do this?

This is the coding which i did:

```
inputFile.get(ch); 
while (!inputFile.eof())  
{
    outputFile.put(toupper(ch)); 
    inputFile.get(ch);
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with coding that you did?

Comment: its capitalizing every word , not only first letter of the word and second its not issuing new line to after fullstop to the output file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To

- Capitalizes first letter of each word
- Insert new lines after `.`

do:

```
bool shouldCapitalize = true;
while (!inputFile.eof())  
{
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    {
        if (shouldCapitalize)
            outputFile.put(toupper(ch));
        else
            outputFile.put(ch);
        shouldCapitalize = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ch == ' ') // before start of word
            shouldCapitalize = true;
        outputFile.put(ch);
    }
    if (ch == '.')
    {
        shouldCapitalize = true;
        outputFile.put('\n');
    }
    inputFile.get(ch);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

More C++ way:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class WordUpper {
public:
    WordUpper() : m_wasLetter( false ) {}
    char operator()( char c );

private:
    bool m_wasLetter;
};

char WordUpper::operator()( char c )
{
    if( isalpha( c ) ) {
       if( !m_wasLetter ) c = toupper( c );
       m_wasLetter = true;
    } else
       m_wasLetter = false;

    return c;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in( "foo.txt" );
    std::ofstream out( "out.txt" );
    std::transform( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>( in ), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>( out ),
                    WordUpper() );
    return 0;
}
```